# Why can't I compile a function using the CHKERRQ macro in PETSc?

Tags: petsc, compiling

I wrote a function to read in the runtime parameters my program takes. This function is in a different file than my main program; the two object files are linked after compilation.

When I compile the file that contains the function I use to read in parameters, I get the following warning:

```
io.c(43): warning #120: return value type does not match the function type
CHKERRQ(ierr);
^
```

This only seems to affect the `CHEKRRQ()` macro, and I don't get this warning when I compile the examples included with PETSc.  The only obvious difference is that the example is entirely within one file whereas my program is broken up into multiple files.

Does PETSc support separate compilation, or does some aspect of the `CHKERRQ()` macro cause problems?

Comment: What type of value does your function return?  int?  void?  Is this consistent with CHEKRRQ?  That is, does the marco assume that your function returns an int?

Comment: The function returns void.

Comment: Further to the above, it seems like your function should return PetscErrorCode.  Here is the manual page: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/CHKERRQ.html

Comment: Ah, I see... since your function returns void, consider using CHKERRV instead of CHKERRQ (or change your function to return PetscErrorCode instead of void).

Comment: Sweet!  Love this site eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHKERRQ` can only be used in functions that return `PetscErrorCode`.

The [PETSc documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/CHKERRQ.html) is reasonably clear here:

> `CHKERRQ` - Checks error code, if non-zero it calls the error handler and then returns
>
> `CHKERRQ(n)` is fundamentally a macro replacement for:

`if (n) return(PetscError(...,n,...));`

> Although typical usage resembles `void CHKERRQ(PetscErrorCode)` as described above, for certain uses it is highly inappropriate to use it in this manner as it invokes `return(PetscErrorCode)`. In particular, it cannot be used in functions which `return(void)` or any other datatype. In these types of functions, you can use `CHKERRV()` which returns without an error code (bad idea since the error is ignored or `if (n) {PetscError(....); return(YourReturnType);}` where you may pass back a `PETSC_NULL` to indicate an error. You can also call `CHKERRABORT(comm,n)` to have `MPI_Abort()` returned immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`CHKERRQ` cannot be used inside functions other than `main()` that don't return `PetscErrorCode`. This is because the `CHKERRQ()` macro is basically

```
if(ierr) {PetscError(..,ierr,..);return ierr;}
```

From the [documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/CHKERRQ.html):

> Although typical usage resembles "void CHKERRQ(PetscErrorCode)" as described above, for certain uses it is highly inappropriate to use it in this manner as it invokes return(PetscErrorCode). In particular, it cannot be used in functions which return(void) or any other datatype. In these types of functions, you can use CHKERRV() which returns without an error code (bad idea since the error is ignored or if (n) {PetscError(....); return(YourReturnType);} where you may pass back a PETSC_NULL to indicate an error. You can also call CHKERRABORT(comm,n) to have MPI_Abort() returned immediately.

Basically, any functions that use `CHKERRQ()` should either return `PetscErrorCode` themselves or use `CHKERRV()` instead.

Comment: CHKERRQ can certainly be used in functions other than main!  Both only in functions whose return is PetscErrorCode

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've edited my answer to reflect that.